# Using Talend with Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, talend

I'm using Talend to export some talend metrics and dimensions in a xls file and it's all working so far.
Now I want to get the Top10Users Data that's visible in the googleAnalytics report.
The problem is that the  Top10Users feature does neither exist in dimensions or metrics. 
So I don't know how to retrieve this information using Talend.

Thank you!

Comment: you cant get top 10 users from The API so i don't think its going to work with talend. You might want to check there documentation.

Comment: I have it as a custom variable in my Google Analytics account dashboard, do you think there a way to get custom variable's results with Talend?